# DatePicker Dialogue Current Date Not getting to select when selecting another dates

Tags: android, datepicker

Hi I am new for android in my app I have created `DatePickerDialogue` ok that's fine

Here my problem is when I selecting any dates other than current date then current date is not able to select

can any one help me plese

### code:-

```
public class DatePickerDialogue extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shared_layout);

        int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(DatePickerDialogue.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    }

                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dpd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to remove this statement dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()); or give some higher value for setMaxDate()

Comment: In my app i have to disable future dates

Comment: That's why i added this line